# An elementary approach using the divisor function definition:

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Proof conclusion: Let m,n,s $\in$ $\mathbb{N} $\ $\{0\}$. Prove that $s| \tau(m^{s}) - \tau(n^{s})$, where $\tau$ is the divisor function.

Hello so my question is that, I've gotten to the point in the proof where I had used the divisor function definition and have $\tau(m^{s})$ = $\prod$ something +1 , and $\tau(n^{s})$ = $\prod$ something +1.

I know, that since the last terms of both polynomials are equal to 1. Somehow this results that $s| \tau(m^{s}) - \tau(n^{s})$.

But I don't understand why the +1 would indicate that: $s| \tau(m^{s}) - \tau(n^{s})$ holds.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491766/divisor-function-tau

Comment: Cool. Nobody responded to that one either. I am just simply wondering how do I justify why I say that because the products are in the product of 

something +1 = > $s| \tau(m^{s}) - \tau(n^{s})$.

Comment: Even when I clicked that duplicate link, they didn't respond rather the first question ignoring this second one which is in my question.

Comment: So this question in particular hasn't been addressed anywhere. And it's just a simple justification. I don't even need it, I just want it for myself. 

Like why is it that the +1 allows me to conclude the proof. I've concluded this proof yes. But I was wondering what the +1 does.

Comment: Oh sweet! I thought I posted something but it didn't go through this morning . Thank you Lord Shark the Unknown!